# Can we use obfuscated fonts in html?

Tags: html, fonts, obfuscation

Does HTML standard allow using an obfuscated font as font-face?
My searches so far indicate that nothing is mentioned about obfuscated font usage in HTML.

Comment: Could you define, specifically, what you mean by "obfuscated font"?

Comment: You mean obfuscation of html code ?

Comment: This should give you an idea of font obfuscation: http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-ocf.html#font-obfuscation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No HTML standard, specification, or draft says anything about the kinds of fonts you can use via `@font-face`, since that belongs to CSS, not HTML. CSS specifications and drafts are silent about that, too.

This applies independently of what you mean by “obfuscated”.